# How do I reduce the cost of set_bit in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql

I am running PostgreSQL 9.6 and am running an experiment on the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE my_bit_varying_test (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  mr_bit_varying BIT VARYING
);
```

Just to understand how much performance I could expect if I was resetting bits on 100,000-bit data concurrently, I wrote a small PL/pgSQL block like this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  t  BIT VARYING(100000) := B'0';
  idd INT;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1..100000
  LOOP
    IF I % 2 = 0 THEN
      t := t || B'1';
    ELSE
      t := t || B'0';
    end if;
  END LOOP ;

  INSERT INTO my_bit_varying_test (mr_bit_varying) VALUES (t) RETURNING id INTO idd;
  UPDATE my_bit_varying_test SET mr_bit_varying = set_bit(mr_bit_varying, 100, 1) WHERE id = idd;
  UPDATE my_bit_varying_test SET mr_bit_varying = set_bit(mr_bit_varying, 99, 1) WHERE id = idd;
  UPDATE my_bit_varying_test SET mr_bit_varying = set_bit(mr_bit_varying, 34587, 1) WHERE id = idd;
  UPDATE my_bit_varying_test SET mr_bit_varying = set_bit(mr_bit_varying, 1, 1) WHERE id = idd;

  FOR I IN 1..100000
  LOOP
    IF I % 2 = 0 THEN
      UPDATE my_bit_varying_test
      SET mr_bit_varying = set_bit(mr_bit_varying, I, 1)
      WHERE id = idd;
    ELSE
      UPDATE my_bit_varying_test
      SET mr_bit_varying = set_bit(mr_bit_varying, I, 0)
      WHERE id = idd;
    end if;
  END LOOP ;
END
$$;
```

When I run the PL/pgSQL though, it takes several minutes to complete, and I've narrowed it down to the for loop that is updating the table.  Is it running slowly because of the compression on the `BIT VARYING` column?  Is there any way to improve the performance?

*Edit* This is a simulated, simplified example.  What this is actually for is that I have tens of thousands of jobs running that each need to report back their status, which updates every few seconds.

Now, I could normalize it and have a "run status" table that held all the workers and their statuses, but that would involve storing tens of thousands of rows.  So, my thought is that I could use a bitmap to store the client and status, and the mask would tell me in order which ones had run and which ones had completed.  The front bit would be used as an "error bit" since I don't need to know exactly which client failed, only that a failure exists.

So for example, you might have 5 workers for one job.  If they all completed, then the status would be "01111", indicating that all jobs were complete, and none of them failed.  If worker number 2 fails, then the status is "111110", indicating that there was an error, and all workers completed except the last one.

So, you can see this as a contrived way of handling large numbers of job statuses.  Of course I'm up for other ideas, but even if I go that route, for the future, I'd still like to know how to update a variable bit quickly, because well, I'm curious.

Comment: Updating in a loop is almost never a good idea performance wise. I also don't understand why you are updating the same row over and over again

Comment: This is a simulated, minimal example.  What will actually happen in production is that there will be thousands of threads simultaneously updating that variable bit row.  If it takes minutes to complete a simple loop like this, then I don't even want to think about what it does with thousands of threads.

Comment: A *simple loop* may kill any software. You should know that the loop creates 100000 rows and deletes 99999 of them. Are you going to say that you'll have 100000 clients simultaneously?

Comment: I'm saying that I might have 10 or 15 clients, but they need to update that row thousands of times.  To clear through the work, each client must perform much better than I'm seeing the updates perform.

Comment: Let me edit the question and see if I can provide more context.

Comment: If each client has it's own row, only this row has to be locked for an update of that client. Given that the client doesn't run concurrent instances of itself, no other client is blocked by that lock. If all are operating on the same row, then they will block each other for sure. I have to admit, that I don't know if the DBMS decides to lock just the rows updated over the whole table in your scenario, but you won't even have a change of the clients not blocking each other, if you let them all work on the same row. I'd definitely try to go with a row per client.

Comment: My thought is that the MVCC nature of Postgres would prevent the locking.  Even if it didn't, then the speed of set_bit is still a problem.  I would wager (though I haven't tested) that adding 1 to an integer column is going to be much faster than set_bit, and that's the part that I don't understand.

Comment: I do not think this is a task for a database server. It seems you need an application running as a server that will perform bit operations in memory and successively send aggregated data to a database.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that answer, but maybe it is the right thing to do.  Hazelcast distributed locking, here I come!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is really the TOAST compression that is your problem, you can simply disable it for that table:

```
ALTER TABLE my_bit_varying_test SET STORAGE EXTERNAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a set based approach to replace the second loop. A set based approach is usually fatser than looping. Use `generate_series()` to get the indexes.

```
UPDATE my_bit_varying_test
       SET mr_bit_varying = set_bit(mr_bit_varying, gs.i, abs(gs.i % 2 - 1))
       FROM generate_series(1, 100000) gs(i)
       WHERE id = idd;
```

Also consider creating an index on `my_bit_varying_test (id)`, if you don't already have one.

Comment: Will the index on the my_bit_varying_test actually help with update performance?  See comment thread above.  There will be many threads trying to update that same row.

Comment: @Brad: Unless the table is small, an index likely helps to retrieve the row that needs to be updated faster, yes. But of course you need to try it and see for yourself, if it helps.